# Where are gzipped files saved by gulp in webapp generated project?

Tags: javascript, build, npm, gulp, yeoman

I scaffolded a project with webapp generator. To scaffold I first downloaded yeoman and generator-webapp. Then I ran the following command:

```
yo webapp
```

Then prompted some options which I set to default(use sass, bootstrap and modernizer). This created a set of floders which contain all the plugins files and a sample html file to start with. After that I ran the following command:

`gulp build`

In console it says:

```
gulp build
[11:01:40] Using gulpfile H:\C\BRQX\Transports\index1\gulpfile.js
[11:01:40] Starting 'lint'...
[11:02:12] Starting 'styles'...
[11:02:26] Starting 'scripts'...
[11:02:41] Starting 'images'...
[11:02:44] Starting 'fonts'...
[11:02:45] Starting 'extras'...
[11:02:45] Finished 'images' after 4.5 s
[11:02:45] Finished 'fonts' after 809 ms
[11:02:49] Finished 'lint' after 1.15 min
[11:02:49] Finished 'scripts' after 24 s
[11:02:49] Finished 'styles' after 37 s
[11:02:49] Starting 'html'...
[11:03:13] Finished 'extras' after 28 s
[11:03:23] Finished 'html' after 34 s
[11:03:23] Starting 'build'...
[11:03:25] build all files 47.24 kB (gzipped)
[11:03:25] Finished 'build' after 1.39 s
```

The build task defined in my gulpfile.js is as:

```
gulp.task('build', ['lint', 'html', 'images', 'fonts', 'extras'], () => {
  return gulp.src('dist/**/*').pipe($.size({title: 'build', gzip: true}));
});
```

Now my question is where do all these gzipped files go? I saw a new folder dist out there but it contains only minified files not gzipped.

Comment: We'll need more information to help you with this. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @henry I read your links and have added more information. plz check if it is sufficient or I add more?

Comment: For starters what does the `build` task look like? With any luck it'll be in the `gulpfile.js` listed at the start of that console readout

Comment: @henry Sorry for my poor English. As far as I could understand your comment, I added the `build` task definition in the question. Is it ok now?

Comment: Have you tried setting `gulp.dest` ?

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing I don't know how to use `gulp.dest`. It is used many times in the `gulpfile.js` but it doesn't seem to be a task. `gulp dest` give error.